# CakePHP 3.x Cookies in two application

Tags: php, cakephp, cookies, cakephp-3.x

I would like my cookies to be visible in several applications within one domain xxx.com. At initialization (AppController.php) of each application I have code:

```
$this->loadComponent('Cookie');

    $this->Cookie->configKey('User',[
        "domain"=>".xxx.com",
        "path"=>"/",
        "expires" => "+10 days",
        "key"=>"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"
    ]);
```

One application initializes the variable User.tmp, but if it is read in another application, it is not visible. Interestingly, the Chrome browser shows that it is set. Is there a hash problem? What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution to the problem:

```
$this->Cookie->configKey('User',[
        "domain"=>".xxx.pl",
        "path"=>"/",
        "expires" => "+10 days",
        "key"=>"1234567890123456789012345678901234567890",
        "httpOnly"=>false,
        "secure"=>false,
        "encryption"=>false
    ]);
```

A cookie is available in one domain. The above solution has some disadvantage: the cookie is not in any way hashed.